# Servlet is invoked only for the default switch case

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Here when the url pattern is "/Login/new" the servlet is not invoked which I verified by printing to console.It works just for the default case that is for "/Login"

```
@WebServlet("/Login")
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    private UserDAO userDAO;
    
    public void init()
    {
        userDAO = new UserDAO();
    }
    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("Servlet invoked !!");
        String action = request.getServletPath();
        System.out.println(action);
        switch(action)
        {
        case "/new":
            showNewForm(request,response);
            break;  
        case "/insert":
            insertUser(request, response);
            break;
        case "/update":
            updateUser(request, response);
            break;
        case "/delete":
            deleteUser(request, response);
            break;
        case "/edit":
            showEditForm(request, response);
            break;
        case "/login":
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher= request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            
            
            
        default:
            //listUser(request,response);
            showLogin(request,response);
            break;
        
        
        }
```

**Output for "/Login":**[[image: Output for "/Login":1]

**Output for "/Login/new":**[image]

The desired output is that the function in "/new" case should be called.What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the path to the following

```
@WebServlet("/Login/*")
```

---

, And try to check that you are retrieving the last part of the path to the URL and lower-case following

```
String action = request.getRequestURI();
action = action.substring(action.lastIndexOf("/")).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Tried this but it gives the same 404 error.The thing is the servlet is not even invoked for "/Login/new" so it never reaches the switch

Comment: Okay, update the path of the servlet I have updated the solution. Hope it will work :)

Comment: Thanks now the servlet is getting invoked for "Login/new" but it still runs the default case in the switch

Comment: I guess we need to check the action URL

Comment: The value stored in ``action`` is still ``"/Login"`` when it should be ``"/new"``

Comment: Try to use `getRequestURI()` rather than `getServletPath()`